# C++: Override keywoard in Sub-subclasses

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a problem with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class C1 {
  public:
  void f() { cout << "something" <<endl; }
};

class C2 : public C1 {
  // void f() { cout << "something more " << endl;}    // no f implementation here
};

class C3 : public C2 {
public:
  void f() { cout << "something else" <<endl; }

};

int main() {
  C1 c1;
  C3 c3;
  c1.f();      // outputs "something"
  c3.f();      // outputs "something else"
  return 0;
}
```

This works fine. But if I mark `C3::f()` with `override` it wont compile ([example on ideone](http://ideone.com/W6bMQZ)). Does anyone know why this happens? Clearly I do override function f successfully here!? Do I misunderstand the idea of the `override` keyword?

Comment: You can only override a virtual function.  Which is what you intended to use but just plain forgot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, member functions are not virtual by default and they must be virtual in order to `override` them (with or without the keyword) in daughter classes. So, your original class needs to be:

```
class C1 {
  public:
  virtual void f() { cout << "something" <<endl; }
};
```

Otherwise you're just hiding it.

Also, override is fairly new - make sure you're using the proper options to invoke c++11.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't even aware of the difference between overriding and hiding.

Answer (score 0):

Override is just a safety net. It tells the compiler that this method MUST exists in the base class and MUST be defined as virtual so that it can be overriden. If any of those requirements are not met, it will cause a compile error. What lets you override a method is only the fact that it has been defined as virtual in a base class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the     overrride    keyword/specifier can only be used to override virtual functions. Documentation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override)

Comment: Had not seen @Etienne Maheu's answer